# Versioning JSON objects in PostgreSQL database with Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb, hibernate-types

I want to store JSON objects in database.

I want my objects to be versioned, and to have them lazily converted to the latest version upon read.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4+ with JPA.

I've already configured `hibernate-types-52` to do the mapping, all works well.

Now, I'd like to be able to read `ObjectV1` in database, and have it converted to `ObjectV2` defined in my JPA entity.

I've been doing this successfully with jOOQ, so I'd like to do the same with JPA.

**Where can I intercept the deserialized object to convert it to the latest version with home made code ?**

I've already configured the object mapper so that the simple name of the class in stored in json in a `@class` field, and all objects stored in database implement a common interface, so that polymorphism should be working fine with Jackson.

I could do the mapping in the getter of the JPA Entity, but I'm looking for a more transparent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have to configure, but you can override the object mapper that is used by setting a system property `hibernate.types.jackson.object.mapper`. Here is the code for getting access to the object mapper: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/blob/master/hibernate-types-52/src/main/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/type/util/Configuration.java#L137

Comment: I've already configured the object mapper. Right I could do the trick there, but I thought there might be a JPA specific layer to intercept that.